# Django template not displaying results in browser

Tags: jquery, django, html, python-3.x, django-forms

I have two Django templates that are dependent, that is, once I hit submit on the form of my first template, I should be redirected to see the results into the second template but I am encountering the error: `NoReverseMatch at /tickets_per_day_results/` where **tickets_per_day_results** is the template that should display the results.

**Forms**

```
class DropDownMenuForm(forms.Form):
    week = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range (1,53)])
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x,x) for x in range (2016,2021)])
```

**Views.py**

```
class ChartData8(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_no_results.html'
    form = DropDownMenuForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    template_name = 'personal_website/tickets_per_day_results.html'
    #print(template_name)
    if request.method == "POST":
        year = request.POST.get('select_year', None)
        week = request.POST.get('select_week', None)
        ... do stuff ....
    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tickets_per_day_no_results/$', ChartData8.as_view()),
url(r'^tickets_per_day_results/$', ChartData8.as_view()),
```

**Template 1: tickets_per_day_no_results**: This is the first template where you select your options from the drop-down menus. My guess is that the action to the second template is causing the problem.

```
{% extends "personal_website/header.html"%}
{% block content %}
<h3>Please, select the year and week number to retrieve the data.</h3>
<form id="search_dates" method="POST" action="/tickets_per_day_results/"> {% csrf_token %}
<h6>Select year</h6>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select name="select_year">
            <option value = {{form.year}}></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h6>Select week</h6>
        <select name="select_week">
            <option value= {{form.week}}></option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Template 2: tickets_per_day_results**: This is the second template where you should see the results.

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}

var endpoint = '/tickets_per_day_results' 

var days_of_data = []
var label_number_days = []

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        label_number_days = data.label_number_days
        days_of_data = data.days_of_data
        setChart()

    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error on data")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
function setGraph(){....}
{% endblock %}
</script>


{% block content %}

<div class ='row'>
    <div class="col-sm-12" url-endpoint='{% url "tickets_per_day_results" %}'>
        <div>
            <canvas id="tickets_per_day" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

How can I fix this problem so I can see the results in the second template in my browser?

Comment: when you call `tickets_per_day_results` it returns html, so in your ajax `data` html, but you need json, or your code is not full.

Comment: When I call `tickets_per_day_results` I should receive a JSON object. I guess the first template is not doing that... The cycle should be like this: `tickets_per_day_no_results` calls `class ChartData8` with the POST method that gives the output of the JSON object that should be received by the `tickets_per_day_results`

Answer (score 0):

Is this defined in some app or something? Is the url completely mentioned in the form? "/tickets_per_day_results/". Can be that you're missing the url suffix relating to the app,that you are mentioning in the root urls.py.  Maybe "something_here/tickets_per_day_results/".